# Code works on two sites, but not on the third

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is very very unusual to me; I've never encountered this.

On this particular domain URL
http://www.flexibleassembly.com/Beta/responsive-beta-II.html,
my *add-to-cart* function is not supposed to display, the only button that should appear is the "*request quote*" button.

The .html file is under the same account, and exact file location. This is being sourced from NetSuite.

On these two domains, the code works perfectly!
http://www.flexibleindustrial.com/Beta/responsive-beta-II.html

http://www.flexiblescientific.com/Beta/responsive-beta-II.html

I can't describe this any better, this is so unique to me that I don't know how to best describe it; other than "my code won't work on one site, but will work on two others"

Like I said, the file location is under the same account each domain is pulling the same file. What would cause this? NetSuite is Cloud-Based; is there anything I need to look for?

**EDIT:**
I forgot to add in the error console (F12), each domain has a different error console output.

**FA -**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (responsive-beta-II.html:1923)
    at j (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
```

On the other two sites, I don't get a single error.

Comment: If you look at the Console (via the F12 tools), there is an error on the "non-working" page that doesn't appear on the other two.  Might it be related to that?

Are all three domains hosted with the same company?

Comment: Yes, same company. I gotta mention that, the error console output varies per domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the following :

```
var sale = "Call For Price";
var basPrc2 = list.split("$")[1];
```

There is no `$` in the `sale`.

Comment: If that's the case, then aren't the other two domains affected by it?

error domain:http://www.flexibleassembly.com/Beta/responsive-beta-II.html

working: http://www.flexibleindustrial.com/Beta/responsive-beta-II.html
working: http://www.flexiblescientific.com/Beta/responsive-beta-II.html

Comment: In the other domains, you have a value of `$XXX,XXX` which works fine for the split.

Comment: that's really odd, why is one domain showing "call for price" over the other two.....

I guess I'll need to make a function for each output

Comment: thanks!!! from me overlooking that variable, I recoded each statement to include the variables if it did not contain "call for price"

Comment: Glad to heat that helps. Please accept the answer if it resolves your problem.

Comment: I will for sure, I also found that "call for price" was being called because the primary domain was FA, since it didnt show on FI/FS actively - NetSuites "salespricehtml" would pull the numeric value and not display "call for price"

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happened, the data provided to me from Karthik VU gave me a new direction.

I discovered that "call for price" is being called when the item is sourcing from domains that it actively displays on.

FA = appears on website, var price = "call for price"
FI/FS = does not appear on site, var price = numeric value

so because of that, it displayed my code two different ways than one. I re-coded my statements and it eliminated the issue.